# <a onClick is calling without clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css

I should use

```
<a href="url">Something/>
```

So when I click on it, it redirects me to my URL.

But now I wanna do the same with the onClick method (to use my router).

In my code I try to use it:

```
<a onClick={this.changeRoute()}>Something/>
```

But this redirects me directly without clicking on it .... 
I expect that the results are that it calls my function after I click on it.
What don't I understand?

Comment: You should show us your actual code, not just some made-up code that might not even include the actual error. Your current HTML is bugged, theres no `</a>` tag. Also what framework are you using? onClick={} is just broken HTML without any framework.

Comment: The library you are using changes that expression `{...}` into executing JavaScript - so it executes immediately. This behavior is different than the `onclick` attribute that is used in a normal HTML anchor tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With parenthesis, you execute the function. To solve your problem, remove it.

```
<a onClick={this.changeRoute}>Something</a>
```

Comment: Please compare this use to ordinary HTML `onclick` attributes - in which one _does_ include the parentheses.

Comment: You will most likely need to bind `this.changeRoute` to `this`, but the most appropriate method depends on the framework that you're using and the version of JS you're writing in.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are calling it right away.
Remove `()` from html.

Should be like this:
`<a onClick={this.changeRoute}>Something/>`

Comment: Please compare this use to ordinary HTML `onclick` attributes - in which one _does_ include the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

By using parentheses you are executing the function and passing the result as the thing to be executed. You are basically saying execute `this.changeRoute()` and onClick do the result of `this.changeRoute()`. Instead you want to do `this.changeRoute()` onClick. You can either do

```
<a onClick={(e) => this.changeRoute()}>Something</a>
```

or

```
<a onClick={this.changeRoute}>Something</a>
```

This first example "ensures `this` is bound within" changeRoute. Otherwise you will have to call a bind function on the function in the second example.

The second example passed the actual function instead of the result of the function.

In other examples, you may want to return a function when `this.changeRoute` is called, in which case your syntax would work just fine, because you would indeed be using the return value as the function to be called.

For more information take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html.

Comment: so the OP is using react then? you know this how?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I could be wrong, but i am pretty sure the answer will work even if it is not React. I assumed it was JSX. If the OP specifies a library that would not work with this answer i will alter or remove it.

Comment: You are wrong. It will not work without parentheses using plain old DOM event handler (`onclick`).

Comment: @JamesBot How did you train a bot to answer questions? 

Comment: Let me be clear. With plain DOM event `onclick`, this will work: `{funcName()}` as one would expect an `onclick` event to work. Given any numerous libraries, it most likley will execute immediately.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yes but i assumed its not "plain old DOM" because of the use of brackets `{}`.